# Using Flash CC to convert AS3 to HTML5,

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, canvas

I’m a complete beginner in HTML/JS, though I’ve written a lot of games in Flash, which I’d like to convert, or at least be able to re-use most of the graphical assets when converting them.

Flash CC proposes to do just that, using the CreateJS libraries, and provides a very basic tutorial, but somehow I cannot make it work (http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2015/04/introduction-to-the-flash-cc-html5-canvas-document.html#comment-376140).

Can somebody give a step-by-step set of instructions for the first time you try to run a canvas app produced with Flash CC? something like: Do I have to set up some plugIn in the browser? how do I do it? do I have to download stuff? what? where do I put it?

Comment: Looking for tutorial is off-topic here. Also, Flash CC is probably not the best tool to create HTML5 websites.

Comment: There really isn't any setup. Create a new HTML5 Canvas document, draw some stuff, and press Test Movie -- it will load up in a browser. @Raptor Flash CC is probably the best graphical IDE for HTML5 Canvas out there.